# filter the_content, custom post type, and wp_query

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, wp-query, the-content

I thought this was going to be quick and easy, but naturally it's turning out to be more complicated.  I'm writing a simple plugin that creates a custom post type "Ad", and then puts a random ad at the bottom of posts.

So I've created my custom post type - that's easy.  Then I created a few ads, and I want to put the featured image from a random ad at the bottom of a post.  So I wrote a function to get a random ad's featured image, and then I wrote a function to filter the content and put the ad at the bottom of the post.

Here's what I have:

```
function wpa_choose_ad() {
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'ad',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,  
        'orderby' => 'rand',             
        );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        $the_ad = the_post_thumbnail();
    endwhile;
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();

    return $the_ad;
}

function wpa_bottom_ad($content) {
    $ad = wpa_choose_ad();

    if( is_single() && is_main_query() ) {
        $content .= $ad;
    }   
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'wpa_bottom_ad');
```

This puts the ad at the top of the post, and does nothing at the bottom of the post.  I think somehow it's running my wp_query at the beginning of the post.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code works for me. I am guessing you have a markup/CSS issue.

Comment: Interesting... I am installing this on a site with an extraordinarily old theme - I suppose it's possible that that's the problem....

Comment: Nope - I just tried it on a site with TwentyEleven, and I see the same problem - the ad appears at the top of the post instead of at the bottom.

Comment: Try replacing `return $the_ad;` with `return 'fake-ad';`. That should tell you if the ad is being placed at the end of the post. If 'fake-ad' shows up at the end of the post the code works and you have an HTML/CSS formatting problem.

Comment: If I replace `return $the_ad'` with `return 'fake-ad'`, then "fake-ad" shows up at the bottom of the post, and the ad still shows at the top.  So the `wpa_choose_ad` function is apparently displaying the ad, then the content is getting filtered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`the_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) is echoing content. You need [`get_the_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) instead. That is your problem.

I believe you should be able to swap this: `$the_ad = the_post_thumbnail();`, for this: `$the_ad = get_the_post_thumbnail();`

Comment: Yes, of course!  I should have thought of that.  Thank you so much!!